# What is Vrect in a Voltage Regulator?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, transformer, converter, switching

I'm just reading through Texas Instruments' Application Report on Switching Regulator Fundamentals and came across the half-bridge converter and the formula for both the output voltage of the entire converter and the peak voltage across the secondary winding of the main transformer. I have included a diagram of the half-bridge in Figure 1 and have included its associated equations in Figure 2. You'll notice that I have highlighted the Vrect term in equation (5) of Figure 2. Can anyone tell me what this Vrect is and where it comes from? Cheers!

Figure 1:

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2:

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Vrect= rectifier diode drop.  Near Ns are 2 diodes that may be Si, or Schottky or other

Answer (score 1):

Vrect refers to the voltage drop of the rectifiers, such that they reduce Vpk by the amount Vdrop. The Vdrop depends on the diode used. Typical fast switching diodes have a forward drop of about 700 mV. Schottky diodes have a forward drop of about 500 mV.

Schottky diodes are used up to 24 VDC outputs, so they cannot be used for 48 or 100 volt outputs. They are more efficient at lower voltages but at voltages below 5 volts synchronous rectifiers are often used to get high efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the voltage drop across the output diode, also known as a rectifier. The equation arises from symmetry: notice that the primary side of the power system has a pair of NPN transistors between the high and low sides of the input "FWB" - full wave bridge, or, usually, full wave rectifier, which are a set of four diodes which convert an AC input signal into something more DC-like.

The voltage across the primary side of the transformer is 1/2 VIN minus the voltage across the switch - the saturation voltage VCE across that NPN. Typical VCE might be 1.5-3V, perhaps, for a standard silicon NPN, but it depends very much on the part and current through the switch. On the secondary side of the transformer, voltage is scaled by the turns ratio - the number of turns on the secondary side divided by the number of turns on the primary side. Finally, the voltage across the output diode or rectifier is lost. If a Schottky diode is used, the voltage is going to be 0.2-0.5V, a silicon diode would lose 0.6-0.8V, etc.